# How I can find exact value in all of third column of array using Python?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

If I have a Numpy array like this:

```
array([0, 0, 0]
      [0, 0, 1]
      [0, 1, 2]
      [0, 1, 3]
      [1, 0, 4]
      [1, 0, 5]
      [1, 1, 6]
      [1, 1, 7])
```

I try using

```
if c==1 in range(X[:,2]):
  print 'yes'
```

but get the error

```
TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

Is it possible to find `c==1` using slicing and an `if` statement?

Comment: StackOverflow is a site where you post questions about a problem you are having, not a list of requirements expecting others to do your work. So have you tried to solve this yourself and ran into a problem? What error did you get? Can you show some code?

Comment: I try using if c==0 in range(X[:,0]): print 'yes' but getting error "TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars"

Comment: @user3794938 Are you trying to find the row which has `1` in the last column?

Comment: yes I'm trying to find the row which has 1 in the third column and if possible I want to using "if" state.. If using slice like "X=X[X[:,2]=2]" I can't do the next step of my project, because I only need to know if a value have in third column so I can update or remove data in my array..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `x[:,2]` gives you the array of element in third column

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> x = np.array([[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 3], [1, 0, 4], [1, 0, 5], [1, 1, 6], [1, 1, 7]])
>>> x
array([[0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1],
       [0, 1, 2],
       [0, 1, 3],
       [1, 0, 4],
       [1, 0, 5],
       [1, 1, 6],
       [1, 1, 7]])
>>> x[:,2]
array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7])
>>> if 1 in x[:,2]:
...     print("yes")
... 
yes
```

Most efficiently like this

```
>>> if np.any(x[:, 2] == 1):
...     print("yes")
... 
yes
>>>
```

Comment: The efficient way of doing this with numpy is `if np.any(x[:, 2] == 1):`

Comment: @Jaime and @Styvane is array with `if` isn't compatible with two conditional? I try with `if np.any(a[:, 0] == 1) and np.any(a[:, 2] == 3):`, it's result `yes` but it should say `no`, because the row is not the same.. is there any other way?

Comment: Try with `np.any((a[:, 0] == 1) & (a[:, 2] == 3))`.

Comment: still say `yes`.. It's seem I'm wrong in the command, can I find first which `column index 0 with value 1` it's should result row 5-8.. And find from the result row, which is have `column index 2 with value 3`, if there's no row that qualify the result should `no`, if there a row so I can `change column index 1 value`

Answer (score 1):

You can use boolean indexing here (rather than looping and using `if`). This is where you use an array of `True`/`False` values to pick out just the rows or columns or values of an array that you want.

The boolean array you need to use to find the row with `1` in the third column is this:

```
>>> X[:, 2] == 1
array([False,  True, False, False, False, False, False, False], dtype=bool)
```

This returns a new array with a value for each row of `X`. It contains `True` if the third column's value is `1` and `False` otherwise.

(You can see that this is what you'd get if you looped over the values of the third column looking for `1`.)

To return the row(s) of `X` with `1` in the third column, just use this boolean array to index `X`:

```
>>> X[X[:, 2] == 1]
array([[0, 0, 1]])
```

Comment: @user3794938: no problem - if you just want to check if `1` is in the third column you can use `if 1 in x[:,2]` like Styvane suggests or else use `(x[:,2] == 1).any()` to get the same result.

Comment: can I ask again ajcr? How if I want to find  if `column index 0` have `value=1` and `column index 2` have `value=4` using if again? I try with `if (a[:,0]==1) & (a[:,2]==7):` but the result seem wrong for me..

Comment: @user3794938: `(a[:,0]==1) & (a[:,2]==4)` is the right way to go about it I think - how do the results seem wrong?

Comment: It's have `ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous` if I use `&`.. If I'm use `if (a[:,0]==1) and (a[:,2]==3):` it's say `yes` it's should say `no` because there's no row which `column index 0 value 1 and have in the column index 2 value 3`

Comment: @user3794938: I think you may want `if ((a[:,0]==1) & (a[:,2]==4)).any():
` - this check if any row of the array has these values for both column 0 and 2.

Comment: yes, that's work thank you so much @ajcr for helping me, this code is works too `if np.where((a[:,0] == 1) & (a[:,2] == 4))[0]:`